# How do I correctly set up systemd-time-wait-sync.service

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-timer

I have to set up a a timer with `onCalendar=*:30` on a Raspberry Pi with **no internet connection** but using instead a battery powered RTC.

To sync my RTC I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305345/sync-system-clock-from-rtc-on-boot/1306410#1306410).

On the [manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.timer.html) of systemd timer under section `OnCalendar=` it is written:
*Note that calendar timers might be triggered at unexpected times if the system's realtime clock is not set correctly. Specifically, on systems that lack a battery-buffered Realtime Clock (RTC) it might be wise to enable systemd-time-wait-sync.service to ensure the clock is adjusted to a network time source before the timer event is set up. Timer units with at least one OnCalendar= expression are automatically ordered after time-sync.target, which systemd-time-wait-sync.service is ordered before.*

My issue is exactly what is described in the man page: the service triggered by my timer triggers immediately when booting instead of `onCalendar=*:30`.

The output of `systemctl status test.timer` yelds:

```
● test.timer - test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Sat 2023-05-13 10:37:17 UTC; 5 months 9 days ago
    Trigger: Sun 2023-10-22 10:55:00 UTC; 2min 56s left
   Triggers: ● test.service
```

You can see `"5 months 9 days ago"` although I just turned on my Raspberry Pi. 
The date `Sat 2023-05-13` is the default when I turn my Raspberry Pi on without RTC.

The man page doesen't help me further. Does someone of you know how to correctly use `systemd-time-wait-sync.service` and what dependencies are required?